# F3 shortcut can't overlap brightness F3 shortcut

Tags: sas, keyboard-shortcuts, custom-keyboard, shortcut, screen-brightness

I just got SAS 9.4 installed at my second Laptop. It's a HP with shortcuts to brigthness at F2+F3. 
It drives me crazy that I can't use F3 or any F-statements in sas because of this overlap. 
Can I do something to "forget" the shortcuts while I'm using the SAS-window? All my F-statements are shortcuts.

Best regards.

Comment: Should be possible.  If you like the mappings then use the fn+F3 in SAS. Or convert your settings so that you need to press the extra "fn" key to dim the lights.  http://h20435.www2.hp.com/t5/The-Next-Bench-Blog/HOW-TO-Disable-The-Fn-Function-on-HP-Laptops/ba-p/77527

Comment: I think this is a question for [SU], not for SO; you really want to tell Windows to stop stealing your function keys, not anything SAS can do about it.

Comment: There may be a bios setting that can change the way the function keys work, depending on your laptop model.

Comment: I think the idea with fn+F3 should be the easiest one. I will do it like that. Thanks for answering.